# Parallel runs in appium on real devices

Tags: java, android, testng, appium

All these days I am running my android test cases using appium on only one connected device to my system

Now i need to run on two devices which was connected to my system with two different ports on appium

I am launching two appium's with different ports I am running two test cases with different capabilities 
But two tests are launching on the same device

I wish to know how to set capabilities so that test will launch on particular device

```
I had tried with this capability but no use
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "TA09401JJY");
```

Please let me know what are the capabilities to set so that test will launch on particular device

Comment: I would assume you'll have to use Grid for that.

Comment: Please let me know how to use Grid I don't know about it

Comment: That's a broad topic. Please google it.

Comment: Try using [QMetry automation framework](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#testing-on-mobile) which is Mobile automation framework for TestNG where you can configure it in xml configuration file outside the code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run parallel tests on separate real devices by starting several instances of appium using unique ports for each.  Then when I would create my appium driver, I would pass the UDID of the device I wanted along with the port of the appium instance that I wanted to use for that specific device.

Here is my streamlined (only 1 device) python code for instantiating the appium driver:

```
from appium import webdriver

def CreateDriver(value):
    appiumHub = None
    port = None

    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['autoAcceptAlerts'] = True
    desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = '120'

    if value == 'iPhone6s':
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS' 
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone1' 
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.3'  

        desired_caps['udid'] = 'df33dh93827364kj3iujgr3g32t22hg878ww7878'

        port = 4723

    appiumHub = 'http://localhost:' + str(port) + '/wd/hub'
    desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.someplace.myapp'

    driver = webdriver.Remote(appiumHub, desired_caps)  

    return driver
```

I had to make copies of my test methods and put them in their own file then passed along what device to run using [ddt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ddt):

```
@data('iPhone6s')
def test_P2A_Accept(self, value):        
    # Some test method
```

Then I would run each test module from a command file (MAC) to get them to run in parallel (and using [py.test](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) for better reporting):

> results=$(date "+Results%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.html")
>
> py.test /Users/jdoe/Documents/workspace/Unit\ Tests\ 2/UnitTests2Package/Python-Selenium/Tests_P2A.py --html=$results --self-contained-html
>
> open $results

Hopefully, there will come a day when we can run multiple devices in parallel from the same test method, but until then this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: Helped me to find solution

Comment: Hi RKelley, were you able to run multiple devices in parallel with same test method?

Comment: @akvenk I had to create a copy of the test methods to have the same tests run in parallel on different devices.  Not ideal, but a workaround until something better comes along.

Answer (score 1):

```
capabilities.setCapability(UDID_KEY, UDID_VALUE);
```

UDID_VALUE is unique for every device.

It can be taken by using adb devices on cmd.